# Catch Unique Key Exception Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Below is the code I use in inserting into the db however when the name of a group which is unique is entered I get a unique key violation in the logs

```
override def create(groups: GroupEntity): Future[GroupEntity] = db.run{groupsTableQuery returning groupsTableQuery += groups}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update however I found a simpler way to solve the problem and this was solved in my route. below is the solution

```
val saved : Future[GroupEntity] = groupRepositoryImpl.create(group) 
onComplete(saved){
case Success(value) => complete(saved.map(_.toJson))
case Failure(ex)    => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))}
```

result => An error occurred: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "groups_name_key_name "
  Detail: Key (groups_name)=(Test Shop) already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Recover using `recoverWith`. As all exceptions will be of type PSQLException, check if certain keywords exist in message of the exception to handle it.

```
val future = db.run { groupsTableQuery returning groupsTableQuery += groups }

future.recoverWith { 
 case ex: PSQLException =>
   val msg = ex.getMessage
   //check message for keywords for specific errors
   Future.successful(0)
 case ex => Future.failed(ex)
}
```